# Center the cursor in the window in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

This is just one of those little things I did all the time in my previous editor that is driving me absolutely insane in Eclipse. I want to be able to jump the cursor to the center-most line of the window. By that I do *not* mean the "Recenter" command, which leaves the cursor where it is and centers the line it's on. I want to move the cursor itself to a new line, the one currently in the middle of the window. Can it be done?

Comment: Eclipse can't do this by default. But you can try to find is there any plugin to do it. The closest way to achieve it is to using CTRL+L to open a dialog and input the number of the line you want to jump to.

Comment: No, there's nothing in Eclipse like that. But I'm very curious (as a power user and someone whose made my living at times developing tools for programmers), what is it that you really are doing when you jump to the line that is "geographically" the center of the editor window? Maybe there's other features of Eclipse that will help you get back whatever efficiency you feel that you've lost.

Comment: In the vim editor for example, this is achieved with the M command. There's not really any ulterior motive other than "I want to edit something that I see near the middle of the screen". Similar commands for the top and the bottom of the screen would also be nice (H and L respectively in vim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code for a handler execute() method to do this. It can be pretty easily hooked up to a command and binding via a plugin.xml file.

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
  IEditorPart editorPart = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditorChecked(event);
  ITextOperationTarget target = (ITextOperationTarget) editorPart
      .getAdapter(ITextOperationTarget.class);
  if (!(target instanceof ITextViewer)) return null;
  ITextViewer textViewer = (ITextViewer) target;
  int topIndex = textViewer.getTopIndex();
  int bottomIndex = textViewer.getBottomIndex();
  int middle = (topIndex + bottomIndex) / 2;
  IDocument doc = textViewer.getDocument();
  try {
    IRegion widgetLineInformation = doc.getLineInformation(middle);
    int widgetOffset = widgetLineInformation.getOffset();
    textViewer.getTextWidget().setSelection(widgetOffset);
  } catch (BadLocationException e) {
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```